# issue installing packages on arch linux (RPi)

Tags: python, linux, archlinux

i keep getting this error. sometimes the error appears with something else on the line but other times it does not.

> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

This happens with nearly every package (worked with python3 and python 2 and a few other things that don’t come to mind now) i did attempt to set the pi to have a fixed IP but i reverted all changes.

Comment: The [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) is only available via HTTPS. Does SSL work for you on the RPi otherwise? Can you request https uris?

Comment: how do I figure that information out? also python was one of the few packages that worked

Comment: Try: ``curl -v -o - https://pypi.python.org/pypi``

Comment: like i said im not having a problem with python. i only mentioned python because it worked.